# Are the closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ precisely the compact connected sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Equip $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology generated by open intervals $(a, b)$. A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it's closed and bounded.

Is every closed bounded connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ a closed interval $[a, b]$ (and conversely)?

Is every open bounded connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ an open interval $(a, b)$ (and conversely)?

Is this somehow related to the fact that removing one point from $\mathbb{R}$ splits it into 2 disconnected pieces (how is this property called anyway)?

Comment: All true if you agree to refer to a point as a closed interval.

Comment: Do you consider $[b,b]= \{b\}$ to be a closed interval?

Comment: No, I'm considering only non-trivial intervals.

Comment: beware also of the title, $[0,+\infty[$ is a closed interval but not bounded.

Comment: Then the answer is no.  But if you did consider [b,b] to be a closed interval (which you are allowed to do or not do as you prefer) the answer would be yes.

Comment: @fleablood Alright, so I guess that means sets of the form [b, b] would be the only "counterexamples"?

Comment: @zwim It is common to call closed an interval with a maximum and a minimum (namely, an interval in the form $[a,b]$ for some $a\le b\in\Bbb R$), therefore, while $[0,\infty[$ is indeed closed in the topological sense, it is not closed in the sense of intervals. This is most likely the case here.

Comment: The nice thing about $\mathbb{R}$ is that connectivity and convexity are the same thing.

Comment: Do you want an informal or formal answer?  It's intuitively obvious that only singletons and intervals are connected.  And intuitively obvious that among finite intervals that only [a,b] are closed (and always closed) and (a,b) are open (and always open), and thus, yes, your statements are all true.  But showing these formally via definitions is ... not hard, but tedious.... but good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly a closed and bounded interval is compact and connected.

Conversely, if a set is connected, then it is an interval, meaning it is a set $I$ with the following property: for all $x,y \in I$, if $x < z<y$, then $z \in I$. All the sets with this property must have one of the forms $$\{a\},\,[a,b],\, ]a,b[, \,[a,b[, \,]a,b], \,]a,+\infty[,\, [a,+\infty[,\, ]-\infty,b[ \mbox{ or } ]-\infty,b].$$
Among these, only $\{a\}$ and $[a,b]$ are compact, hence the answer to your question is *yes*. Notice that $\{a\}$ is an interval, by definition.

Comment: Thank you. What about the 2nd question, about open sets?

Comment: Also yes, with the same reasoning: use connectedness to narrow the list of "suspects" and then see that the only open bounded set in that list is $]a,b[$.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma 1:  Only intervals and singletons and the empty set are connected and all intervals and singletons and the empty set are are connected.

Lemma Z: $K\subset \mathbb R$ is a interval if and only if for all $x,y \in K$ then for all $k; x < k < y; k \in K$.

Proof:  Should be self-evident.  If $K$ is an interval than $K = [(a,b)]$ (for sake of notation $a$ can be $-\infty$ and $b$ can be $\infty$). and $a \le x < y \le b$ and for all $k: x < k < y$ then $a < k < y$ so $k \in K$.

If there exists a $k$ so that $x < k < y$ with $k \not \in K$ and $x,y \in K$ then there is no $a,b$ (not even $\pm \infty$) so that $a \le x; b \ge y$ and for all $r \in \mathbb R$ $a < r < b$; $r \in K$. (as $a < k < b$ but $k \not \in K$).  So $K$ would not be an interval.

Proof of Lemma 1: If $K$ = $\emptyset$ or $K = \{x\}$, some singleton then $K$ can not be partitioned into two partitions so $K$ is connected.

Let $E \subset \mathbb R$.  And let $E$ be such that there exist $x,y\in E; x< y $ and there exists a $k \not \in \mathbb R$ so that $x < k < y$.  Let $A = E \cap (\infty, k)$ and $B= E \cap (k, \infty)$ then $A, B$ are non-empty partitions of $E$ and $\overline A \subset (-\infty,k]$ is disjoint from $B \subset (k,\infty)$ and $\overline B \subset [k,\infty)$ is disjoint from $A \subset (-\infty, k)$ so $E$ is not connected.

So the only connected subsets of $E$ are intervals, singletons, and the empty set.

If $K$ is an interval and $K = A\cup B$ and $A,B$ non empty and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.  Let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ and wolog $a < b$.  Let $K = \{x| x \ge a; \forall k; a\le k \le x: k \in A\}$ and let $L = \{y \in K| y > a; y \in B\}$.  It's easy to prove $K$ is non-empty $(a \in K)$ and bounded above (by $b$) and $ L$ is non-empty ($b$ is in it) and bounded below (by $a$) and that $\sup L = \inf L$. As $K$ is an interval and $a \le j = \sup K = \inf L\le b$ then $j \in K$.  And $j \in \overline A$ and $k \in \overline B$.  So either $j \in \overline A \cap B$ or $j \in \overline B \cap A$.  So $K$ is connected.

Comment: My edit was solely  to add a missing dollar-sign that  disrupted some of the formatting.